# How to clear a notification from notifications window but keeping the notification window open

Tags: android, notifications

I would like to send several notifications to the status bar and allow the user to close each notification individually. I can do that with the following lines:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0);
```

... but clicking on one notification clears the notification itself but also closes the notification window.

I was wondering if it is possible to clear a notification from notifications window but keeping the notification window open in order to continue clearing other notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on notification it takes you to the respective application. nd close the notification window. its a default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the notification id for that particular notification you wanted to close.

```
public void clearMessageNotification(long notificationId) {
        FileLogUtils.d(TAG, "clearMessageNotification");
        observeTotalUnreadCount();
        if (notificationId == 0) {
            clearChatSummaryNotification();
            return;
        }

        notificationManager.cancel((int) notificationId);
        try { // TODO: 2019-12-25 remove after finding the cause for android.os.DeadSystemException
            StatusBarNotification[] activeNotifications = notificationManager.getActiveNotifications();
            if (activeNotifications != null) {
                FileLogUtils.d(TAG, "clearMessageNotification ActiveNotifications : " + activeNotifications.length);
                if (activeNotifications.length <= 1) {
                    notificationManager.cancel(MESSAGE_SUMMARY_ID);
                } else {
                    Single.fromCallable(() -> {
                        updateNotificationSummary();
                        return true;
                    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

and if you want to close all the notifications

```
public void clearAllNotifications() {
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
        NotificationUtils.updateBadgeCount(context, 0);
    }
```